# Regarding gem file editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I executed 'gem install mongoid' and 'gem install bundler' to work with MongoDB in Rubyonrails these two commands executed with out any errors but when i am trying to execute bundle update 
I am getting errors like Bundler could not find compatible version for gem "äctivemodel" in Gemfile:.I am new to ruby programming rails and mongodb can you help me to resolve this isssue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by deleting the lock rm Gemfile.lock and again running bundle install